# Javascript command to check values in set?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to find a creative way/patch in order to minimize this line :

```
 if(myParam == '1' || myParam == 'a' || myParam == '*' || myParam == '@' || myParam == undefined || myParam == null || myParam == ' ')
    {...
    }
```

One solution is the use indexOf - but it is not cross browser
*(I  could write my own func to behave like indexOf - but I dont want to ).*

So I tried the  `in` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

But the in operator deals only with *object properties names* and *indexes*

So I tried this (object properties):

```
   if(window.lala in {
    '*': 0,
    'a': 0,
    '@': 0,
    ' ': 0,
    undefined: 0,
    null: 0
}) alert('1')
```

and I think it is working.

2 question please :

<kbd>question #1</kbd>

is it safe for property name to be [`undefined`] or [`' '`] or [`null`] ? will it always work ?

<kbd>question #2</kbd>
Is there any other solution for doing this ?

*(Case/switch can be done too, I know... )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have won't work for undefined.  You can have a property named `"undefined"`, but that's a string name, not the actual `undefined` value.  You may get a match via type conversion, but it will also match if you have a string named `"undefined"` too which is not something you want.

I would suggest a more explicit test that uses `===` to avoid any type conversions.  There are several ways to do it that are slightly less verbose than what you had:

```
if (myParam === null || myParam === undefined || 
    (myParam && myParam.length == 1 && "1a*@ ".indexOf(myParam) !== -1) {
   // code here
}
```

Or you can make an array and your own cross browser function (or use a polyfill for `Array.indexOf()` to search an array which can hold all the values:

```
function inArray(val, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === val) {
            return(true);
        }
    }
    return(false);
}

var testValues = [null, undefined, "1", "a", "*", "@", " "];
if (inArray(window.lala, array)) {
    // your code here
}
```

You can use the object form you were experimenting with and just use explicit tests for `null` and `undefined`, but I think the `string.indexOf()` suggestion in my first proposal is simpler.  Anyway, here's a safe form using the object

```
if (myParam === null || myParam === undefined || 
    (myParam && (myParam in {"*":0, "1":0, "a":0, "@":0, " ":0})) {
   // code here
}
```

My recommendation would be the first option as I think it's the cleanest and it's also really easy to extend by just adding more chars to the test string.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - but the property name in your test object is not `undefined`.  All property names are strings so `undefined !== "undefined"` so it won't match in your object lookup.

Comment: I dont get it. `if(undefined in {
    '0': 0,
    '*': 0,
    'a': 0,
    '@': 0,
    ' ': 0,
    undefined: 0,
    null: 0
}) alert('1') //` it does alert

Comment: @jfriend00: When you use `in`, the value you test for will be converted to a string. That's why it "works".

Comment: @RoyiNamir - you are living dangerously via a type conversion.  Note that `if("undefined" in { '0': 0, '*': 0, 'a': 0, '@': 0, ' ': 0, undefined: 0, null: 0 }) alert('1')` runs the alert too.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you wanted to tell _me_ that :-)

Comment: @FelixKling - I know that - but that means that the test is no longer testing just the `undefined` value.  It also passes the test if it is given a string `"undefined"` which is not what the OP said they wanted to happen.  Type conversions are generally evil and can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: I know... I guess I got all confused by you guys going back and forth saying it works or does not work for `undefined` :D It depends on the perspective ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it safe for property name to be `[undefined]` or `[' '`] or `[null]` ? will it always work?

All property names are converted to strings, which means you cannot distinguish between the number `0` and the string `'0'` and not between the value `null` (`undefined`) and the string `'null'` (`'undefined'`).

Treating numbers as numeric strings is probably fine in your case, for `undefined` and `null`, I would just add an extra test:

```
if(value == null || value in exclude) {
    // ...
}
```

`value == null` is `true` if `value` is `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

1: it's better to use 'undefined' and 'null' as names of your object, because when you walk through it with for in loop it checks for string representations of a property(you can check it if you do a:

```
 for(prop in obj) typeof(prop) //this will be a string
```

2: You can also store your values in array and do recursion:

```
 var vals = ['*', 'a', '@', ' ', undefined, null], param = '@', i = 0;

function checkVals(param, vals, i) {
    if (vals[i] && param === vals[i]) {
        console.log(1);
        return;
    } 

    checkVals(param, vals, i + 1);
}

checkVals(param, vals, i);
```

Comment: Why would you use recursion instead of a simple loop?

Comment: You can use simple loop if you want. I just show one way how this problem can be solved :)